Taiwind styles through className variables not working in ReactNative
I am using
"nativewind": "^2.0.11", as "dependencies"
and
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2", as "devDependencies"
Normal css styling operations using tailwind are working fine. However I am having trouble passing css classes put together as javascript constants. Sometimes it works, sometime it does not.
Here is the complete scenario.
I,
define some constants in ./assets/style/style.js file, as:
export const text__title = 'mb-1 text-xl font-poppins-semibold'
export const text__gray = 'mb-2 font-poppins text-sm text-neutral-400 leading-4'
export const text__inputLabel = 'text-xs font-poppins-semibold mb-1 text-fasteezy-300'

Import them in the forget.tsx component:
import * as twStyle from '@/assets/style/style'

And use it in the styled and/or simple View and Text elements:
<StyledText className={twStyle.text__title}>Forgot Password</StyledText>
<StyledText className={twStyle.text__gray}>Please enter the email you would like your password reset information sent to.</StyledText>
<Text className={twStyle.text__inputLabel}>{name}</Text>

But nothing works, and it keeps it plain for everything.

However if I add, styles directly into the tags, they seem to work. See below:
<StyledText className="mb-1 text-xl font-poppins-semibold">Forgot Password</StyledText>
<StyledText className="mb-2 font-poppins text-sm text-neutral-400 leading-4">Please enter the email you would like your password reset information sent to.</StyledText>
<Text className="text-xs font-poppins-semibold mb-1 text-fasteezy-300">{name}</Text>


Here is the contents of tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require("./theme/colors")
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors,
      fontFamily: {
        "poppins": ["PoppinsRegular"],
        "poppins-medium": ["PoppinsMedium"],
        "poppins-bold": ["PoppinsBold"],
        "poppins-semibold": ["PoppinsSemiBold"],
        "poppins-light": ["PoppinsLight"],
        "poppins-black": ["PoppinsBlack"],
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}

And ./theme/colors.js
module.exports = {
  'fasteezy': {
    100: '#cffafe',
    200: '#a5f3fc',
    300: '#FFC670',
    400: '#22d3ee',
    500: '#06b6d4',
    600: '#0891b2',
    700: '#0e7490',
    800: '#155e75',
    900: '#164e63',
  },
}

printing console.log just before the component's return function prints them fine:
console.log(twStyle.view__frmrow)
console.log(twStyle.view__inputwrap)
console.log(twStyle.text__inputLabel)
...
output...
LOG  mb-3.5 content-center justify-center
LOG  px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg border-slate-200
LOG  text-xs font-poppins-semibold mb-1 text-fasteezy-300

Passing constants to className had been working since yesterday, but today I made a change into color.js to change the value of a color 300 and it suddenly stopped working.
Here is the output of tailwind
Any idea what wrong I am doing?

when you used a variable for className, did you use a template literal?

@odri - I am not sure I get you. Can you be more precise?

className={twStyle.text__title} className={\${twStyle.text__title}`}`

It does not make any difference. I was using template literal earlier, and thought it might be causing the issue. None of both works though :)

Either I am issing something or #Nativewind seems unstable. I am very frustrated since yesterday.

<Text className={\${twStyle.text__inputLabel}`}>{name}does not work while printing the variable printstext-xs font-poppins-semibold mb-1 text-fasteezy-300, which, if I put directly in the className` value it works.

I am reverting back to using static classes within tags until I or someone found a solution :(
